# Hang on button press

Tags: java, android, freeze

I've got a weird problem. I've got this android app that should get some data from a URL that leads to a text file. It has 18 lines and one item per line, and looks something like this:

> Mastercard
>
> name
>
> 123456789
>
> 1004
>
> 56
>
> 5000

(this is an assignment, all data is obviously fake)

I have this:

```
public class CreditCard {

    //set up method to get and return data as arraylist
    public ArrayList<String> ccArray(){
        ArrayList<String> ccInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

        //array set up. time to get data
        try {
            URL urlDat = new URL("url");
            Scanner urlScn = new Scanner(urlDat.openStream());
            while (urlScn.hasNext()){
                ccArray().add(urlScn.nextLine() + "\n");
            }

        }catch (MalformedURLException URLe){
            //handle exception

        }
        catch (IOException IOe){
            //handle exception
        }
        return ccInfo;
    }
}
```

So I can pass the array to the main method (or another method in the class, not sure yet). I have a button that that runs displayCreditCards in the main method:

```
public void displayCreditCards(View view) throws IOException {
        TextView tv1;

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_main);
        tv1.setText("Data will appear here");

        //create objects to det data and make profiles
        CreditCard ccObj = new CreditCard();


        tv1.setText(ccObj.ccArray().toString());
}
```

However, this causes the application to not respond, and I get the wait/close dialog from android. I'm not sure how to interpret the logcat:

```
10-04 18:27:01.204    9036-9036/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-04 18:27:01.204    9036-9036/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
10-04 18:27:01.206    9036-9036/? I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
10-04 18:27:01.257    9036-9036/? W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.pat.displaycc-2/lib/x86
10-04 18:27:01.396    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-04 18:27:01.400    9036-9036/com.example.pat.displaycc D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad7ad9a0, tid 9036
10-04 18:27:01.468    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad7ade40, tid 9058
10-04 18:27:01.471    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-04 18:27:01.520    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-04 18:27:01.521    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7917c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-04 18:27:04.841    9036-9036/com.example.pat.displaycc W/art﹕ Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
10-04 18:27:04.874    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-04 18:27:04.874    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad791c20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-04 18:27:06.138    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab80f0d0
10-04 18:27:11.564    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-04 18:27:11.564    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad791c00, error=EGL_SUCCESS
10-04 18:27:13.108    9036-9058/com.example.pat.displaycc E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab80f060
```

I've no idea why it hangs on me, any ideas?

Comment: Network calls should only be done in thread other than Main (UI). Call this ` ccArray()` from a thread (like Handle, AsyncTask, Thread).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you don't close the scanner after its use. you should always add a finally {} block after the try-catch where you should call

```
urlScan.close() and
urlDat.close()
```

Comment: I'm getting a can't resolve symbol when I add a finally{}. No error when I add it after the while loop, but now it crashes with an out of memory error.

Comment: oops! you should also close the urlDat input stream.  urlDat.close()